# Static Callbacks in Abstract Base class C++

Tags: c++, oop, templates, callback, c++builder

I’ve got an OOP / design problem that I have run into and am desperately hoping that someone can steer me in a direction that doesn’t require a complete re-write.

The system is essential a Windows Service that have ~9 secondary threads that are responsible for specific tasks. All the threads share some common functionality (for example, the ability to send and receive messages internally etc). Because of this, I defined an abstract base class from which all the threads inherit from.

However, four of the threads also make use of an Inter-Process communication system based on a 3rd-party IPC system (madshi’s CreateIpcQueue ). To save replicating all the same code in these four threads, I defined an additional class to support this:

```
TThread <-TBaseThread<-TIPCBaseThread<- Four IPC threads
               ^- All other threads.
```

The mechanics of the IPC system is that you define a Callback function and then call the CreateIpcQueue passing it this Callback.  In my TIPCBaseThread I loosely did something like this:

```
// TIPCBaseThread.h
class TIPCBaseThread : public TBaseThread
{
 private:
   static TIPCBaseThrd *pThis; 
   // defines the callback to use with the IPC queue 
   static void CALLBACK IPCQueue(char *cName, void *pMsgBuf, unsigned int iMsgLen, 
                                 void *pRtnBuf, unsigned int iRtnLen);
 protected:
   // virtual method, to be defined in derived classes, to handle IPC message
   virtual void ProcessIPCMsg(char *cName, void *pMsgBuf, unsigned int iMsgLen, void *pRtnBuf, 
                              unsigned int iRtnLen) = 0;
 public:
   CRITICAL_SECTION csIPCCritSect;
 …

// TIPCBaseThread.cpp
TIPCBaseThrd* TIPCBaseThrd::pThis = 0;

__fastcall TIPCBaseThread::TIPCBaseThread(…) : TBaseThread(…)
{
  pThis = this;
  InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&csIPCCritSect, 1000);
  CreateIpcQueueEx(“SomeQueueName”, IPCQueue, 1, 0x1000);
                                     //^Callback Queue
  …
}

void CALLBACK TIPCBaseThread::IPCQueue(char *cName, void *pMsgBuf, unsigned int iMsgLen, 
                                       void *pRtnBuf, unsigned int iRtnLen)
{
  EnterCriticalSection(&pThis->csIPCCritSect);
  pThis->ProcessIPCMsg(cName, pMsgBuf, iMsgLen, pRtnBuf, iRtnLen);
  LeaveCriticalSection(&pThis->csIPCCritSect);
}
```

My general thinking was that the TIPCBaseThread would effectively take care of creating and managing the IPC channel and then call the ProcessIPCMsg() in the various derived classes.

Now, when I test the system and send a message to any of the IPC channels, the message is received in the TIPCBaseThread callback but is passed up to the last derived class (to be created), not the class that should receive it. I’m assuming it is something to do with the

```
[static TIPCBaseThrd *pThis]
```

property being overwritten when each derived class is instantiated (but I confess I’m not 100% sure)?

Could anyone steer me in the right direction here? Obviously I would like to know exactly what is causing the problem but ideally I would like to know if there is a work around that would avoid having to completely re-write the whole object inheritance – there is obviously a bit more going on under the hood than I have shown and I’m going to have serious problems if I have to abandon this design completely.

Many thanks in advance,

Mike Collins

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change the callback to take the instance as an argument

```
static void CALLBACK IPCQueue(TIPCBaseThread *instance, 
                              char *cName, void *pMsgBuf, unsigned int iMsgLen, 
                              void *pRtnBuf, unsigned int iRtnLen);
```

...

```
void CALLBACK TIPCBaseThread::IPCQueue(char *cName, void *pMsgBuf, unsigned int iMsgLen, 
                                       void *pRtnBuf, unsigned int iRtnLen)

{
  ...
  instance->ProcessIPCMsg(cName, pMsgBuf, iMsgLen, pRtnBuf, iRtnLen);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hay chaptrap - thanks for the suggestion.  I should really have clarified this more.  What you are suggesting is an ideal solution however... the callback prototype is defined by the 3rd-party developer and thus, I can’t add or modify the parameters within it.

Comment: Ah ok, gotcha. Maybe you could create a map based on some id (name?) and a pointer to the instances then in the callback use that to find the right instance.

Answer (score 0):

There is one very strange thing: `pThis = this;` with `static TIPCBaseThrd *pThis;`

It means that at any point in time only the latest instance of `TIPCBaseThrd` is accessible via `pThis` (all previous instances having been overwritten); and of course there is the issue that this global value is not protected by any kind of synchronisation (mutex, atomics, ...)

It's unfortunate, but this `static TIPCBaseThrd *pThis;` is just an horrible idea that cannot possibly work.

Comment: Agreed... As you have highlighted, this is in essence a *hack*.  Since the callback is defined as static, this was the only way I could make the callback see the base class.  The background to this is that I was migrating a previous development over to RAD XE2.  During this migration, I decided to introduce some structed OOP into the design.  In the original code base, each thread had this structure and thus it wasnt a problem.  However, in this new design, it clearly it - obviously becuase it doesnt work, and also because of the sync issues that you have highlighted...

Comment: @user2244208: OOP is not the only way to introduce structure, if it does not fit do not use it :)